# No se visualiza correctamente el precio y el precio promocional

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs

Tengo un problema en que cuando los precios de mis productos superan los 7 numeros,se vizualiza mal el orden de los valores y no muestra tachado el precio original (Muestro imagen)

[image: Fijense en la impresora que remarco y en la diferencia con el kit para electronico silver arriba al medio]

Este es mi HTML con Angular

```
<!--<div ng-show="!inStock" class="overlay"></div>-->
            <div class="details {{element.alignment_details}} {{element.show_info}}" ng-show="element.show_price || element.show_name || element.show_button">
                <dl class="info_details">
                    <dt class="name">
                        <span ng-style="{{element.style.name}}" ng-show="element.show_name">{{element.name}}</span>
                    </dt>
                    <dd ng-show="element.price && Math.ceil(element.price) > 0 && !element.promo_price && element.show_price" class="product_without_promo_price">
                        <span class="price" ng-style="element.style.price">{{element.label_price}} {{element.price | defaultCurrency}}</span>
                    </dd>
                    <dd ng-show="element.price && Math.ceil(element.price) > 0 && element.promo_price && element.show_price" class="product_with_promo_price">
                        <span class="price promo_price" ng-style="{{element.style.price}}">{{element.label_promo_price}} {{element.promo_price | defaultCurrency}}</span>
                        <span class="price old_price" ng-style="{{element.style.promo_price}}" ng-if=" element.label_promo_price == '' ">{{element.price | defaultCurrency}}</span>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                <div>
                    <div class="buy_button" ng-style="{{element.style.buyButton}}" ng-show="element.show_button">
                       {{element.text_button | translate}}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

y mi HTML con los datos de length y max number.

```
<span class="flex-price">
            <input type="text"
                   class="nomProdInput currencyFormat priceInput"
                   maxlength="15"
                   maxnumber="999999999"
                   value="<?php echo $price?>"
                   <?php if ($lockPrice): ?>readonly<?php endif; ?>/>
        </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo hacer una directiva con la vista para cada uno de esos, ejemplo aqui https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-qs4sjz, intenta forzar con un